# Django: manage.py does not print stack trace for errors

Tags: python, django, debugging, stack-trace

In Django, most of the time when I run `manage.py` and it encounters an error, I don't get the full stack trace for the error, just the text of the exception, making it very hard to debug. Example:

```
python manage.py graph_models -a -g -o my_project.png
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '__module__'
```

(This is for the graph_models add-on, but it also occurs for built in commands. The only exception I found is `runserver`, which encounters the same errors as the other commands but prints the full stack trace)

Here is my manage.py file. My project was originally created for Django 1.1, but I recently upgraded to 1.5.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os, sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "ctree.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Have you tried passing the `--traceback` argument?

e.g:

```
python manage.py graph_models --traceback -a -g -o my_project.png
```

Comment: Excellent! That worked! Looks like in the development version of Django this is now enabled by default, which seems like the logical way to go: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-option---traceback