# The least helpful error ever: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: python, django, testing, fsm

I just re-wrote a large chunk of Django code that had to do with a 40-something state FSM. There are a lot of STATE_DEFINITIONS = "4.7.1" for each of the three models involved, and lots of checks if the current state == SOME_STATE or in [ONE_STATE, OR_ANOTHER].

There is only one place in which I use a dictionary. say one of the models looks like:

```
class OneModel(models.Model):
    STATUS_ONE = "1.0"
    STATUS_TWO = "2.0"

    STATUS_MAPPING = {
              STATUS_ONE:OtherModel.STATUS_X,
              STATUS_TWO:OtherModels.STATUS_Y,
    }
```

All the keys are unique strings, and if I remove it from the code the same thing happens.

When I `python manage.py test my_app` I get what is probably the least helpful error message ever:
`TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`
That's it, no line where it happens, no context. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to debug this that does not involve going line by line of the 800+ in the file?

Comment: Passing a list in as the key to a dictionary, but lists are mutable so cannot be dictionary keys.

Comment: Is the current state being used in a set or as a dict key anywhere?

Comment: See this for a workaround that may well work:  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581572/django-manage-py-does-not-print-stack-trace-for-errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581572/django-manage-py-does-not-print-stack-trace-for-errors)

Comment: If you convert your list to a tuple, you may be able to use it as a dict or set key.  However, you'd also want the elements of the tuple to be immutable first.

Comment: Please read the question. The problem I'm facing is finding where in my code the error is happening. --traceback did it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try passing the `--traceback` option.

Answer (score 0):

Check `manage.py` for exception swallowing behavior; may be something like:

```
try:
    ....
except Exception, exc:
    print exc.message
```

If you find it, make it `raise` instead so you can see whole traceback.

Comment: Manage.py is really thin, just a wraper around `execute_from_command_line` in `django.core.management`, I'll have to dig deeper into it. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

If you have ipython installed, you can try:`ipython -i manage.py test my_app`. then input `%debug` command to debug it.

Comment: Ok, downloading iPython. Been meaning to try it for a while. Will report what I find once it downloads